# Using dynamic ip in debian but with a static local ip from the router

Tags: debian, ip

Is this possible? If so how do I set my static local ip to 192.168.0.2?

Right now im using this in my /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2 
netmask 255.255.255.0  
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

But it doesnt seem to work because I cannot ping anything.

When I enter ifconfig it doesnt even show eth0. I have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: For a start your default gateway not in your network. Your ip should be probably 192.168.1.2 or gateway's IP should be 192.168.0.1 or DHCP server on the router configured incorrectly, which I find highly not probable.

Comment: To be honest I doubt I even set the gateway right. The computer is connected to a router that can be accessed from 192.168.0.1 if that is any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eth0 might not be up?

1. make sure you have a line saying "auto eth0" in your interfaces file.
2. in order to activate the interface right away, do "ifup eth0". This that doesn't make your interface show up in ifconfig (or produce an error message) there is something more fundamental amiss.

Comment: I got it to work temporarily with "ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.10.255" and "route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 eth0". I have no lien saying "auto eth0" in my interfaces file though. Will adding it solve the problem?

Comment: Adding auto eth0 seemed to solve this problem. Thank you :)